# set-aduser attributes different than AD properties?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I type `help set-aduser` at the PowerShell command line, I get the information listed below. The property that I am interested in changing is the office.

According to the information listed below, that attribute is specified as `-office`. But there is no attribute in AD named office, it is actually `physicalDeliveryOfficeName`. Do they both refer to the same attribute in AD? Why is this, I would think that I can just specify the LDAP name?

```
NAME
    Set-ADUser

SYNOPSIS
    Modifies an Active Directory user.

SYNTAX
    Set-ADUser [-Identity] <ADUser> 
    [-AccountExpirationDate <System.Nullable[System.DateTime]>] 
    [-AccountNotDelegated <System.Nullable[bool]>] [-Add <hashtable>] 
    [-AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption <System.Nullable[bool]>] 
    [-CannotChangePassword <System.Nullable[bool]>] [-Certificates <hashtable>] 
    [-ChangePasswordAtLogon <System.Nullable[bool]>] [-City <string>] 
    [-Clear <string[]>] [-Company <string>] [-Country <string>] [-Department <string>] 
    [-Description <string>] [-DisplayName <string>] [-Division <string>] 
    [-EmailAddress <string>] [-EmployeeID <string>] [-EmployeeNumber <string>] 
    [-Enabled <System.Nullable[bool]>] [-Fax <string>] [-GivenName <string>] 
    [-HomeDirectory <string>] [-HomeDrive <string>] [-HomePage <string>] 
    [-HomePhone <string>] [-Initials <string>] [-LogonWorkstations <string>] 
    [-Manager <ADUser>] [-MobilePhone <string>] [-Office <string>] 
    [-OfficePhone <string>] [-Organization <string>] [-OtherName <string>] 
    [-PasswordNeverExpires <System.Nullable[bool]>] 
    [-PasswordNotRequired <System.Nullable[bool]>] [-POBox <string>] 
    [-PostalCode <string>] [-ProfilePath <string>] 
    [-Remove <hashtable>] [-Replace <hashtable>] [-SamAccountName <string>] 
    [-ScriptPath <string>] [-ServicePrincipalNames <hashtable>] 
    [-SmartcardLogonRequired <System.Nullable[bool]>] [-State <string>] 
    [-StreetAddress <string>] [-Surname <string>] [-Title <string>] 
    [-TrustedForDelegation <System.Nullable[bool]>] 
    [-UserPrincipalName <string>] [-AuthType {Negotiate | Basic}] 
    [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Partition <string>] [-PassThru <switch>] 
    [-Server <string>] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-ADUser -Instance <ADUser> [-SamAccountName <string>] [-AuthType {Negotiate | Basic}] [-Credential <PSCredential
    >] [-Partition <string>] [-PassThru <switch>] [-Server <string>] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: How do you create an ADUser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command line :

```
Set-ADUser admInst1 -Office "##OFFICE##"
```

Set the `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` attribute.

As you can see here :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer LDAP names, you can use them with the -Remove, -Add, -Replace or -Clear parameters instead of any of the regular parameters that are different than LDAP names.  Place the attributes and values in a hash table, separate multiple attributes with semicolons and multiple values with commas.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity CitizenRon -Replace @{physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Downtown;mail=citizenron@somewhere.com;telephoneNumber=888-888-8888;otherTelephone=999-999-9999,777-777-7777}
```

Answer (score 5):

They are one and the same. For a list of the extended properties available through the powershell active directory cmdlets, and the lDAPDisplayName they each refer to you can reference:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx

I assume they offer 'office' instead of the LDAP name for convenience since it is considerably shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I used DistinquishedName to find the manager by name.  You have to find the ADUser rather than inject the distinquishedName string into Set-AdUser

```
$manager_user=Get-ADUser -Filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$manager'" -SearchBase "ou=ChildOU,ou=ParentOU,dc=abc,dc=corp,dc=com" 
                        Set-AdUser -Identity $user.SID -Credential $credential -Manager $manager_user -Server DC2.abc.corp.com
```